# JTable won't update after adding data

Tags: java, swing, jtable

`JTable` doesn't update after adding rows from SQL Server 2008 database.

Using Netbeans 8.2 on jaybird 2.2.5 I have tried moving the `setModel()` to different places, I've used `fireTableDataChanged()` and `repaint()` and nothing happens.

```
String[] colNames = {"#", "Name", "Surname", "Grades", "House", "Prefect"};
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(colNames, 0);
Validation.newStudent(db, stringName, stringSurname); //Creates a new row with a name and a surname
int maxval = Integer.parseInt(Validation.getNumberOfStudents(db)); //Counts the amount of students in the table

String[][] rowData = new String[maxval][50];
model.setRowCount(0); //to reset the rows
for (int i = 0; i < maxval; i++){
    String[] row = new String[maxval];

    for (int j = 0; j < maxval; j++){

        rowData[i][0] = Integer.toString(i+1);
        rowData[i][1] = Validation.listStudentNames(db).get(i);
        rowData[i][2] = Validation.listStudentSurnames(db).get(i);
        rowData[i][3] = Validation.studentsByGrade(db).get(i);
        rowData[i][4] = Validation.studentsByHouse(db).get(i);


        if (Validation.listPrefects(db).get(i) == null){ //checks if a student is a prefect
            rowData[i][5] = "No";
        }else{
            rowData[i][5] = "Yes";
        }

        row[j] = rowData[i][j];
    }
    model.addRow(row); 
}teacherContentTable.setModel(model);
```

The table is supposed to update with the new student but it keeps an old table model.

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Hard code data to replace the DB.

Comment: If you are using Jaybird (the JDBC driver for Firebird), then how is SQL Server involved? In any case, nothing in the code shown seems to be database related.

Comment: I'm probably wrong, I'm on my first semester in uni, I just know the methods used to populate the 2d array are using SQL statements to get data from a database and that so far SQL Server syntax has been working for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't answer your question, but your logic for repopulating the model is overly complex.

There is no need to create a 2D array since you add the data to the model one row at one time.

Also, just use a Vector, since the DefaultTableModel will convert the row array to a Vector anyways.

So the basic structure of your code would be more like:

```
String[] colNames = {"#", "Name", "Surname", "Grades", "House", "Prefect"};
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(colNames, 0);
Validation.newStudent(db, stringName, stringSurname); 
int maxval = Integer.parseInt(Validation.getNumberOfStudents(db)); 

for (int i = 0; i < maxval; i++)
{
    Vector<String> row = new Vector<String>();

    for (int j = 0; j < maxval; j++){

        row.add( Integer.toString(i+1) );
        row.add( Validation.listStudentNames(db).get(i) );
        row.add( Validation.listStudentSurnames(db).get(i) );
        ...
    }

    System.out.println( row ); // make sure you actually add data to the model.
    model.addRow(row); 
}

teacherContentTable.setModel(model);
```

Now assuming you actually added data to the model the table will be updated, again assuming your have a proper reference to the JTable instance that was added to the frame.

Edit:

The above code is really irrelevant to your stated problem of updating a JTable with a new model.

It can be replaced with a single line of code:

```
teacherContentTable.setModel( new DefaultTableModel(5, 5) );
```

You should now see an empty JTable with 5 rows and columns. You get this working first before worrying about getting data from the database.

Comment: I just tried this and it still doesn't update. Maybe it's worth to note that I had to set a new variable for the model because "model" had already been initialized earlier? And I am referring to the correct JTable. The JTable is in JScrollPane which is in a JPanel within a JTabbedPane if that makes a difference. There are more JTables in the other tabs. Thanks for teaching me about vectors, btw, I have like 10 more of these convoluted code blocks...

Comment: I forgot to see the println in the console, hang on

Comment: Ok so it printed all the values up til index 7, but I know the amount of rows in the database is 16.

Comment: So you have multiple problems: 1) you can't update the table 2) you can't get all the data from the database. So you need to solve one problem ad a time. So first you need to learn to update a JTable with hard coded data. So start by creating a JFrame with a JTable with a DefaultTableModel with 5 rows and 5 columns (actual data is irrelevant). 2) Then you add a button to the frame. When you click the button you replace the model with a new DefaultTableModel with 3 rows and 7 columns (again the data is irrelevant). This will prove to yourself that the setModel(...) method works.

Comment: So I tried a different SQL statement that returns a smaller arraylist than the rest and this time it only got to 4. Meaning one of the arraylists returned by the database methods cap at 7, so I'm now wondering how to keep iterating when an arraylist ends...

Comment: Forget about the database. Read my edit and above comment. Learn the basics of using a TableModel first. We can't help you with your SQL logic because we don't have access to your database and we don't know what the Validation class does.

Comment: I did both your edit and your comment. Your edit gave me the same jtable that capped at 4 rows. As for your comment it worked and I knew it would bc I know the basics.

Comment: `Your edit gave me the same jtable that capped at 4 rows` - so then you don't have a reference to the JTable that is visible on the frame. Do basic debugging to determine why. That is when you create the JTable add a display statement. When you attempt to update the model of the table do another display statement. The reference should be the same in both cases.

Comment: Apparently it doesn't even get to that point in the code, I tried println with the jtable and just a "hello" and nothing.

Comment: I put it in the finally clause as println(teacherContentTable) and on its creation and they don't print the same thing

Comment: Right so as I suggested from the start, you don't have a reference to the table so you need to debug your code to figure out why, because the code you posted in your question is not the problem. You must create two instances of the JTable somewhere.

Comment: I didn't realize it was possible since they shared the same variable name :( and I don't follow, what is the point of creating two instances? How do I even do that

Comment: `How do I even do that` - I don't know how you did that. That is why you have been asked to create an [mre]. The point of the "MRC" is to simplify the code. So get it working with simple code and then add more logic and test. Then add more logic and test. When it stops working you know what you just changed and you know where the problem is. We can't help you based on the information provided

Comment: `what is the point of creating two instances?` - there is no point and that is your bug you need to solve. Maybe you don't create two instances of the JTable directly, but maybe you create two instances of the class that create the JTable.